# Sum Based on Criteria Matching a Space Separated List

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image]
I'm trying to populate the table by adding all fruits by month and year (ignoring the days)
This would be simple using a pivot table But

How can I correct the formula to match only the fruit name before the space? (like text to column space delimited)

Something like `=LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1)-1)` into the formula.
Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Same formula, but replace `$F2` with `$F2&" *"`

Comment: Or if there's a possibility that column A might contain an entry that does not have a space, you can just use the asterisk `$F2&"*"`

Comment: Did you see my response to you from the old post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with $F2 & " *"
Thank you!